# else is not working when called by function

Tags: java

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    //For String
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //For Letter
    Scanner word = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name;
     //Input For a String
    System.out.println("Enter A String");
        name = input.nextLine(); 



    //Input For a Char
    char letter[] = new char[3];
    System.out.println("Enter a Letter You Want to Search ");
    for(char c : letter)
        letter = word.nextLine().toCharArray();

    elfish(letter, name);

}

public static void elfish(char letter[], String name) {
     if(name.toLowerCase().contains(name.valueOf(letter).toLowerCase())) {
        System.out.println("Yes The Letter Contains Elfish");
     } else {
        System.out.println("You're Word is not in this String");
        }
}
```

i m making the program which is near to completion. It actually searches the desired letter in the string and if condition is true is prints the "if block" and if condition is false "else block" should run but actually its not working now. only "if block" is working. "else block" was also working fine until it was directly placed in main function. please tell me where what is wrong.

Comment: Run it with a debugger and you will figure it out.

Comment: **Always** use braces when using a for loop. `elfish(letter, name);` is executed just once.

Comment: Do you want to search single character or three characters?

Comment: `name.valueOf(letter)` should be `String.valueOf(letter)` or `new String(letter)`.

Comment: `for(char c : letter) letter = word.nextLine().toCharArray();` does not do what you think it does. Don't know for sure what you think it does, but that is just *wrong*.

Comment: Sir then correct me kindly ... i will be grateful

Comment: *"its not working now"* is not a description of your problem. In what way is it not working?

Comment: `It actually searches the desired letter in the string` - so why are you trying to read a "letter" into an Array that can contain 3 characters? Shouldn't you just read in  a single character?

Comment: sir actually if the three of my desired letters are not present in the string then else block must run and it is not working ... Actually it was working fine when it was in the main function as soon as i shift it into the user defined function it is not working.

Comment: You should definitely [read the Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). Your code shows that you do not understand fully the thing you're trying to address.

Comment: @camickr, Sir Actually you're i must search just one character. but now i have to search the three characters(my desired characters) into the string. now reason behind the array of character is that i have to take three character at once to search in the string and this was the only possible way to me at the moment

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to iterate through letter before putting anything in the array.  If you take out the `for` loop, (leaving the assignment of `letter`) the code should run properly in many cases.  I do not know how you want to validate input.

I'm guessing you are new.  Learning to use a debugger can be overwhelming, but it is a powerful tool.  It'll be slightly different for every debugger and IDE but the process is the same.

A little more info here: [Breakpoints and step by step debug in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497866/breakpoints-and-step-by-step-debug-in-java)

However, in this instance finding a guide for your IDE on Google might be the best option.